# How to set timer for before voice record in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to I phone programming.I working on one project in that i want to set particular time for before voice recording.In segment controller i have give some value that i have store that values  inside variable.If click on that segment button inside that button some value i have given that value i want to fix in this code how to do this.Can any body help me

```
[recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)5];
```

In above code in place of 5 i want to give segment controller variable value like if i select 10 means .The value of 10 fix in place of 5.similarly if i select 15 means value of 15 fix in place of 10 how to do this can any help me.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
[recorder recordForDuration:intvalue];
```

or,

This may help to solve your problem.

After started recoring call the record stop function by setting the timer like below.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stoprecord)withObject:nil afterDelay:intvalue];
```

set int value to any integer you want

```
-(void) stoprecord
{
   [recorder stop]
}
```

Comment: hey i want to set timer before voice recording how to do this

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what you are asking. It seems like you need to know how to replace the 5 with a more dynamic variable so you can change it at run-time. But I did have to read it a couple of times as your question is quite confusing in the grammar.

Comment: get the integer value in static variable before recording